# how to create a VTCompressionSession in swift?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, swift, xcode6

I have been looking high and low for *how to create a* **VTCompressionSession** (*in* **swift**) as briefly mentioned in the [2014 WWDC Video - 'Direct Access to Video Encoding and Decoding'](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/).

The following code works in Objective-C:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <VideoToolbox/VideoToolbox.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        VTCompressionSessionRef session;
        VTCompressionSessionCreate(NULL, 500, 500, kCMVideoCodecType_H264, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &session);

        NSLog(@"created VTCompressionSession");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But no matter what I have tried I cannot find a way to import `VTCompressionSessionCreate` to **swift**.

```
import Foundation
import VideoToolbox

VideoToolbox.VTCompressionSessionCreate()

println("created VTCompressionSession")
```

This code for instance breaks with: `Module 'VideoToolbox' has no member named 'VTCompressionSessionCreate'`.
Just calling `VTCompressionSessionCreate` creates the error message `Use of unresolved identifier 'VTCompressionSessionCreate'`.

It looks like it the API is not exposed in **swift**, since I can call methods like `VTCompressionSessionEncodeFrame` just fine. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My workaround is to write an objective-c function and expose it via a bridging-header to swift:

Compression.h

```
#import <VideoToolbox/VideoToolbox.h>
VTCompressionSessionRef CreateCompressionSession();
```

Compression.m

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <VideoToolbox/VideoToolbox.h>

VTCompressionSessionRef CreateCompressionSession(){
    NSLog(@"CreateCompressionSession");
    VTCompressionSessionRef session;
    VTCompressionSessionCreate(NULL, 500, 500, kCMVideoCodecType_H264, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &session);
    return session;
}
```

stream-Bridging-Header.h

```
#import "CompressionSession.h"
```

Now you can run the following code in **swift**:

```
import Cocoa
import Foundation
import VideoToolbox

let session = CreateCompressionSession()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it in swift:

```
var session: Unmanaged<VTCompressionSession>?
VTCompressionSessionCreate(nil, 320, 200, CMVideoCodecType(kCMVideoCodecType_H264), nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, &session)
compressionSession = session?.takeRetainedValue()
```

where

```
var compressionSession: VTCompressionSessionRef?
```

Do not forget to `import CoreMedia`

Comment: This example no longer (if it ever worked) works on OS X 10.10 or iOS 8. Passing nil in for the `VTCompressionSessionCreate` outputCallback parameter (8th parameter) gives a error code -12092.

Comment: The above will give type error.  In xcode 7/swift 2 the following might work:
    var session: UnsafeMutablePointer<VTCompressionSession?> = nil
    
let status = VTCompressionSessionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, Int32(pixelWidth), Int32(pixelHeight), kCMVideoCodecType_H264, nil, nil, nil /* uses default */, nil, nil, session)

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3:

```
var compressionSesionOut = UnsafeMutablePointer<VTCompressionSession?>.allocate(capacity: 1)
VTCompressionSessionCreate(nil, 100, 100, kCMVideoCodecType_H264, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, compressionSesionOut)
```

Then, you can access it like this, for example:

```
let vtCompressionSession: VTCompressionSession = compressionSesionOut.pointee.unsafelyUnwrapped
VTSessionSetProperty(vtCompressionSession, kVTCompressionPropertyKey_RealTime, kCFBooleanTrue)
```